# elasticsearch-php multiple range query not working

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using a client for elasticsearch [client for elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-php), i am not getting the right result for a multiple range query.

The body that i use for querying:

```
{  
   "index":"locations",
   "type":"portugal",
   "body":{  
      "aggs":{  
         "unique":{  
            "aggs":{  
               "documents":{  
                  "top_hits":{  
                     "size":50
                  }
               }
            },
            "terms":{  
               "field":"cp3"
            }
         }
      },
      "query":{  
         "filtered":{  
            "filter":{  
               "bool":{  
                  "must":{  
                     "range":{  
                        "latitude":{  
                           "gte":41.1373667,
                           "lte":41.1373767
                        },
                        "longitude":{  
                           "gte":-8.631723,
                           "lte":-8.631713
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

the result:

```
{  
   "took":2,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{  
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{  
      "total":1,
      "max_score":1,
      "hits":[  
         {  
            "_index":"locations",
            "_type":"portugal",
            "_id":"AVTJ4I0g_vwSgXBDKO-W",
            "_score":1,
            "_source":{  
               "id":222956,
               "latitude":41.0383217,
               "longitude":-8.6317147
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "aggregations":{  
      "unique":{  
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
         "sum_other_doc_count":0,
         "buckets":[  
            {  
               "key":199,
               "doc_count":1,
               "documents":{  
                  "hits":{  
                     "total":1,
                     "max_score":1,
                     "hits":[  
                        {  
                           "_index":"locations",
                           "_type":"portugal",
                           "_id":"AVTJ4I0g_vwSgXBDKO-W",
                           "_score":1,
                           "_source":{  
                              "id":222956,
                              "latitude":41.0383217,
                              "longitude":-8.6317147
                           }
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

as you can see the result's latitude is not inside the latitude range i gave it.

Using the Head plugin from elasticsearch to test:

my query:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "latitude":{  
                     "gte":"41.1363671",
                     "lte":"41.1363771"
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "longitude":{  
                     "gt":"-8.6318828",
                     "lte":"-8.6318728"
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "must_not":[  

         ],
         "should":[  

         ]
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":10,
   "sort":[  

   ],
   "aggs":{  

   }
}
```

The result:
 (empty), there is no records in this range.

Edit:
added the mapping for my index:

```
{     
      "locations":{  
      "aliases":{  

      },
      "mappings":{  
         "portugal":{  
            "properties":{  
               "cp3":{  
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "cp4":{  
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "cpalf":{  
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "id":{  
                  "type":"long"
               },
               "latitude":{  
                  "type":"double"
               },
               "localidade":{  
                  "type":"string"
               },
               "longitude":{  
                  "type":"double"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings":{  
         "index":{  
            "creation_date":"1463675755006",
            "number_of_shards":"5",
            "number_of_replicas":"1",
            "uuid":"C9OO0ig_QyeigqSufK8_dA",
            "version":{  
               "created":"2030199"
            }
         }
      },
      "warmers":{  

      }    
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can show the mapping and settings?

Comment: Check this : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14161 . This should be help

Comment: `{
"locations": {
"aliases": {},
"mappings": {
"portugal": {
"properties": {
"cp3": {
"type": "long"
},
"cp4": {
"type": "long"
},
"cpalf": {
"type": "string"
},
"id": {
"type": "long"
},
"latitude": {
"type": "double"
},
"localidade": {
"type": "string"
},
"longitude": {
"type": "double"
}
}
}
},
"settings": {
"index": {
"creation_date": "1463675755006",
"number_of_shards": "5",
"number_of_replicas": "1",
"uuid": "C9OO0ig_QyeigqSufK8_dA",
"version": {
"created": "2030199"
}
}
},
"warmers": {}
}
}`

Comment: check the below answer. Did it help you, @GustavoSilva ?

Comment: On PHP-elasticsearch, i was not sending a JSON as body, i was sending an array, and the elasticsearch client was converting it. When i tried to send one like the one you posted, there was a response error by elasticsearch. My query was right after i removed the "term" from it. I still don´t know why it was not working like it should. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Test with the following query :

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "bool":{  
         "must":[  
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "latitude":{  
                     "gte": 41.1363671,
                     "lte": 41.1363771
                  }
               }
            },
            {  
               "range":{  
                  "longitude":{  
                     "gt": -8.6318828,
                     "lte": -8.6318728
                  }
               }
            }
         ],
         "must_not":[  

         ],
         "should":[  

         ]
      }
   },
   "from":0,
   "size":10,
   "sort":[  

   ],
   "aggs":{  

   }
}
```

As longitude and latitude fields are double type the should be compare with double, but you have compared with string.